# Interpolate stroke width between points in Paper.js

Tags: javascript, svg, paperjs

I am using Paper.js to create some shapes. It has worked great so far. One thing where I am stuck is variable stroke width. I want to stroke width to change between different points just like the color changes in gradients. Here is some code:

```
var firstSegment = new Segment({
    point: [100, 50],
    handleOut: [80, 100]
});

var secondSegment = new Segment({
    point: [300, 50],
    handleIn: [-80, -100]
});

var path = new Path({
    segments: [firstSegment, secondSegment],
    strokeColor: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 4
});
```

In the above example, the `strokeWidth` is 4 everywhere along the path. How can I create a path such that it starts with a stroke width of 1px and then gets 6px wide at the other end?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, there is currently no easy way to achieve this, which internally requires a bezier curve offset algorithm. Have a look at this thread to have an idea of the state of this kind of thing: https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues/371 This said, for simple cases like your example (which uses only straight lines), you could find a descent workaround.

Comment: Thanks @sasensi. :)